# Problema con celdas tabla html

Tags: html, html5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es el espacio d las fotos (la primera y la segunda) ya que tiene que quedar como en la foto, pero en mi caso el final de la primera foto no queda en mitad del td (bodegas de...)

no me puedo creer que este preguntando esto :facepalm:

Comment: Hola, ayudaría mucho si pudieras compartir tu código y posiblemente la liga a tus imágenes. Saludos.

Comment: Con tablas no es posible, porque el rowspan es con enteros y, en tu caso, se necesitarían decimales... o, en su defecto, una tabla dentro donde calcules altura de todas las celdas de la izquierda y asignes 50% para el contenedor de cada imagen.